# How do I create this page transition?

Tags: css, sass, css-transitions, barbajs

I've been trying to create this page transition, https://alitwotimes.com/ , specifically the one between 'work' and 'bio'. I've tried with swup.js and barba.js but I haven't had any luck, I could just be using them incorrectly though.

I'm not looking for the code, but I'm just hoping someone will be able to point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: is this what you are looking for?
https://jsfiddle.net/KennyChoy/cgqbptv9/15/

Comment: @Kenny that fiddle doesnt seem to work for me, nothing happens when i click bio or work, or is it just meant to be used as a reference?

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood. I thought you're talking about the style of 'bio and work'.
https://jsfiddle.net/KennyChoy/mjx0g7yn/4/

Comment: @Kenny wow thanks thats awesome! if you want you can post as an answer and ill select as correct. either way thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GSAP can definitely do this.

See this GSAP example, almost the exact same: https://krotravelengineering.jp/

More on the free GSAP library: https://greensock.com/gsap/

Comment: Doing a little inspecting on that site it looks like they're using gsap `GSAP 3.0.1`

Comment: cool thank u! do you think GSAP alone is capable of doing this or will I need to use another library with it like swup or barba?